# How to get total cost of start package table between two periods by sql query?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database, erd

**Problem**: how to get total cost  of start package table between two periods with a SQL query?

```
alexaPackage  from 28/06/2017 to 05/07/2017 8days  cost ?
```

**Details**

I need to get total cost in start package table between two dates, start date and end date. This cost between two periods represent cost of hotels found on every packages depend on period per every hotel price.

Image of diagram and view all data

[diagram and view of data][1]

Package table:

```
    PackageID   PackageName   Duration
        p1         sfinx         8
        p2         alexa         8,15
```

PackageDuration table:

```
PackageDurationID  PackageID  Duration NightCount
PD01                   p2        8        7
PD02                   p2        15       14

DurationDetails table:

    DetailDurationID   PackageDurationID   Days
    DD01                     PD01          DAY1
    DD02                     PD01          DAY2
    DD03                     PD01          DAY3
    DD04                     PD01          DAY4
    DD05                     PD01          DAY5
    DD06                     PD01          DAY6
    DD07                     PD01          DAY7
    DD08                     PD01          DAY8
```

DayDetails table:

```
DayDetailID  DetailDurationID  HotelID
DayD01        DD01                01
DayD02        DD02                01
DayD03        DD03                01
DayD04        DD04                02
DayD05        DD05                02
DayD06        DD06                02
DayD07        DD07                02
DayD08        DD08                01
```

Hotel table:

```
HotelID  HotelName
01        Hilton
02        Movenpick
```

HotelPrice table:

```
HotelPriceID    FromDate   ToDate     HotelPrice HotelID
HP01            01/01/2017 30/06/2017 20          01
HP02            01/07/2017 31/12/2017 30          01
HP03            01/01/2017 30/06/2017 30          02
HP04            01/07/2017 31/12/2017 40          02
```

StartPackage table:

```
StartID   PackageID  StartDate   EndDate     TotalCost
SD01       p2        28/06/2017  05/07/2017   250
```

Calculate cost for total cost column:

```
date          cost
28/06/2017     20 
29/06/2017     20
30/06/2017     20
01/07/2017     40
02/07/2017     40
03/07/2017     40
04/07/2017     40
05/07/2017     30 
totalpackage  250
```

Database script

```
 USE [NileTravel3]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DayDetails]    Script Date: 14/07/2017 11:16:59 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails](
    [DayDetailsID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DetailsDurationID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [HotelID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DayDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DayDetailsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DurationDetails]    Script Date: 14/07/2017 11:17:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DurationDetails](
    [DetailsDurationID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PackageDurationsID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Days] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DurationDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DetailsDurationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Hotel]    Script Date: 14/07/2017 11:17:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hotel](
    [HotelID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [HotelName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Rating] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HotelID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[HotelPrice]    Script Date: 14/07/2017 11:17:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HotelPrice](
    [HotelPriceID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FromDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ToDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [HotelPrice] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [HotelID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductPrice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HotelPriceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Package]    Script Date: 14/07/2017 11:17:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Package](
    [PackageID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PackageName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Duration] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Package] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PackageDuration]    Script Date: 14/07/2017 11:17:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PackageDuration](
    [PackageDurationsID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PackageID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PackageDuration] [int] NULL,
    [NightCounts] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageDuration] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageDurationsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[StartPackage]    Script Date: 14/07/2017 11:17:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StartPackage](
    [StartID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PackageID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TotalCost] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StartPackage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StartID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[View_1]    Script Date: 14/07/2017 11:17:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_1]
AS
SELECT        dbo.Package.PackageName, dbo.Package.Duration, dbo.PackageDuration.PackageDuration, dbo.PackageDuration.NightCounts, dbo.DurationDetails.Days, 
                         dbo.Hotel.HotelName, dbo.HotelPrice.FromDate, dbo.HotelPrice.ToDate, dbo.HotelPrice.HotelPrice
FROM            dbo.Package INNER JOIN
                         dbo.PackageDuration ON dbo.Package.PackageID = dbo.PackageDuration.PackageID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.DurationDetails ON dbo.PackageDuration.PackageDurationsID = dbo.DurationDetails.PackageDurationsID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.DayDetails ON dbo.DurationDetails.DetailsDurationID = dbo.DayDetails.DetailsDurationID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Hotel ON dbo.DayDetails.HotelID = dbo.Hotel.HotelID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.HotelPrice ON dbo.Hotel.HotelID = dbo.HotelPrice.HotelID

GO
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'DDD01', N'DD01', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'DDD02', N'DD02', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'DDD03', N'DD03', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'DDD04', N'DD04', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'DDD05', N'DD05', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'DDD06', N'DD06', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'DDD07', N'DD07', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[DayDetails] ([DayDetailsID], [DetailsDurationID], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'DDD08', N'DD08', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD01', N'PD01', N'DAY1')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD02', N'PD01', N'DAY2')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD03', N'PD01', N'DAY3')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD04', N'PD01', N'DAY4')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD05', N'PD01', N'DAY5')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD06', N'PD01', N'DAY6')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD07', N'PD01', N'DAY7')
INSERT [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID], [PackageDurationsID], [Days]) VALUES (N'DD08', N'PD01', N'DAY8')
INSERT [dbo].[Hotel] ([HotelID], [HotelName], [Rating]) VALUES (1, N'Hilton', N'***')
INSERT [dbo].[Hotel] ([HotelID], [HotelName], [Rating]) VALUES (2, N'Movenpick', N'**')
INSERT [dbo].[HotelPrice] ([HotelPriceID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [HotelPrice], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'HP01', CAST(0x0000A6EE00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A7A200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(20 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[HotelPrice] ([HotelPriceID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [HotelPrice], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'HP02', CAST(0x0000A7A300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A85A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[HotelPrice] ([HotelPriceID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [HotelPrice], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'HP03', CAST(0x0000A6EE00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A7A200000000 AS DateTime), CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[HotelPrice] ([HotelPriceID], [FromDate], [ToDate], [HotelPrice], [HotelID]) VALUES (N'HP04', CAST(0x0000A7A300000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A85A00000000 AS DateTime), CAST(40 AS Decimal(18, 0)), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Package] ([PackageID], [PackageName], [Duration]) VALUES (N'P02', N'AlexaPackage', N'8,15')
INSERT [dbo].[PackageDuration] ([PackageDurationsID], [PackageID], [PackageDuration], [NightCounts]) VALUES (N'PD01', N'P02', 8, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[PackageDuration] ([PackageDurationsID], [PackageID], [PackageDuration], [NightCounts]) VALUES (N'PD02', N'P02', 15, 14)
INSERT [dbo].[StartPackage] ([StartID], [PackageID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [TotalCost]) VALUES (N'SD01', N'P02', CAST(0x0000A7A000000000 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A7A700000000 AS DateTime), CAST(250 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DayDetails_DurationDetails] FOREIGN KEY([DetailsDurationID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[DurationDetails] ([DetailsDurationID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DayDetails_DurationDetails]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DayDetails_Hotel] FOREIGN KEY([HotelID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotel] ([HotelID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DayDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DayDetails_Hotel]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DurationDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DurationDetails_ProgramDuration] FOREIGN KEY([PackageDurationsID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PackageDuration] ([PackageDurationsID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DurationDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DurationDetails_ProgramDuration]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HotelPrice]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_HotelPrice_Hotel] FOREIGN KEY([HotelID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotel] ([HotelID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HotelPrice] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_HotelPrice_Hotel]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PackageDuration]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageDuration_Package] FOREIGN KEY([PackageID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Package] ([PackageID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PackageDuration] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageDuration_Package]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StartPackage]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StartPackage_Package] FOREIGN KEY([PackageID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Package] ([PackageID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StartPackage] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StartPackage_Package]
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value=N'[0E232FF0-B466-11cf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[42] 4[1] 2[17] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 2 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [56] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 7
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 8
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1[56] 4[18] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 9
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [75] 4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 10
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1[66] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 11
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [60] 2))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 12
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(H (1) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 13
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 14
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (2))"
      End
      ActivePaneConfig = 0
   End
   Begin DiagramPane = 
      Begin Origin = 
         Top = 0
         Left = 0
      End
      Begin Tables = 
         Begin Table = "Package"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 38
               Bottom = 118
               Right = 208
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "PackageDuration"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 246
               Bottom = 135
               Right = 441
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "DurationDetails"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 0
               Left = 469
               Bottom = 112
               Right = 664
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "DayDetails"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 120
               Left = 38
               Bottom = 232
               Right = 219
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "Hotel"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 138
               Left = 257
               Bottom = 250
               Right = 427
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
         Begin Table = "HotelPrice"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 118
               Left = 478
               Bottom = 247
               Right = 648
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 1
         End
      End
   End
   Begin SQLPane = 
   End
   Begin DataPane = 
      Begin ParameterDefaults = ""
      End
      Begin ColumnWidths = 12
         Width = 284
         Width = 1500
         W' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'View_1'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane2', @value=N'idth = 1080
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
         Width = 780
         Width = 1290
         Width = 1275
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1155
         Width = 1500
         Width = 1500
      End
   End
   Begin CriteriaPane = 
      Begin ColumnWidths = 11
         Column = 1440
         Alias = 570
         Table = 1170
         Output = 720
         Append = 1400
         NewValue = 1170
         SortType = 1350
         SortOrder = 1410
         GroupBy = 1350
         Filter = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
      End
   End
End
' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'View_1'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPaneCount', @value=2 , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'View_1'
GO
```

Comment: What an awesome job posting ddl and sample data!!! I wish more people would take such effort making their post this nice. I don't understand what you expect for output though. The explanation you posted about the output just has me scratching my head at the moment.

Comment: I only need sql query clalculate price between two period in start package table

Comment: I don't understand. The StartPackage table is empty.

Comment: what i remove in my post to be nice

Comment: Help me understand what you want and I can help you get the data.

Comment: I show you in example how i calculate package

Comment: I need sql query get totalcost price between two dates in start package table

Comment: Where is this example? You have something at the top that says something about Alexa package. But you state the duration is 8 days. The duration for that package is 4 days.

Comment: I understand that you want to get the information to populate StartPackage but it makes no sense at all to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: I write until day8

Comment: How does that make any sense? The package is for 4 days. I don't understand why you won't put in the minute amount of effort to explain what you want. You clearly spent a lot of time putting together the hard part. You don't even state what hotel to use as a cost. Of course in the first part of your post you state the alexa package is 8 days, but in your sample data it is 4 days.

Comment: I update original post it now 8 days

Comment: can you see under detail section the following example i write it if possible

Comment: I give up. You are not making this clear at all. How could anybody provide a price from this? You have different prices on hotels but nowhere do you state which hotel to use for a price. Your data model seems to be flawed. You have a package but you don't have a way to relate that package to a hotel and you don't provide the hotel in your explanation. I hope you can figure this out but I am done spending my time on this. Good luck.

Comment: let me prepare may data and i will post

Comment: first of all im sorry for posting flaw data

Comment: I update my database with correct data as example above can you please see it

Comment: can you please see it i update my original post

Comment: can you tell me what is not clear to explain to you